# Question on Conditional Probabilities

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

This one is from Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon Ross. Not homework, was just trying to solve through some exercises again.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables with rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively. Let $M=\min(X,Y)$.

Find :

\begin{align}
E[MX|M=X]\\E[MX|M=Y]\\Cov(X,M)
\end{align}

What I tried:
\begin{align}
E[MX|M=X]&=E[X^2]\\&=\dfrac{1}{\lambda^2}+\dfrac{1}{\lambda^2}\\&=\dfrac{2}{\lambda^2}
\end{align}
The solutions at the back of the book do:
$$E[MX|M=X]=E[M^2]=\dfrac{2}{(\lambda+\mu)^2}$$
I didn't proceed any further since there was a discrepancy on the first step itself.

How should I be solving this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ must be the rates, not the means.

$M$ is an exponential random variable with rate $\lambda + \mu$.  Think of
a Poisson process with rate $\lambda + \mu$, where each occurrence is independently assigned to 
the $X$ process with probability $\lambda/(\lambda+\mu)$, otherwise to the $Y$ process.

$M=X$ means the first occurrence of the process is assigned to the $X$ process.
This event is independent of $M$, but not of $X$.  So $E[MX | M=X] = E[M^2 | M = X] = E[M^2]$.

Comment: I don't follow the last paragraph. "M=X means the first occurrence of the process is assigned to the X process" If $M=X$, I would think that the minimum of the two random variables is $X$. So, I replace $M$ by $X$ in the numerator.

Comment: $X$ is the time of the first occurrence that is assigned to the $X$ process, $Y$ is the time of the first occurrence that is assigned to the $Y$ process.  $M = \min(X,Y)$ is the time of the first occurrence.  If this first occurrence is assigned to the $X$ process, then $M=X$ and $Y > M$.  If the first occurrence is assigned to the $Y$ process, then $M=Y$ and $X > M$.

Comment: OK. I think I am understanding this. So, you have a "superimposed" poisson process where M represents the first occurence of either of the events. But, I still don't follow why $M=X$ is independent of $M$ but not $X$. I can't figure out why it is true mathematically and it is not intuitive

Comment: Suppose $X$ is very large.  It's extremely likely then that $Y < X$, and therefore that $M \ne X$.  On the other hand, suppose $X$ is very small.  It's extremely likely then that $Y > X$, and therefore that $M=X$.  So $M=X$ is not independent of $X$.

Comment: On the other hand, no matter what $M$ is, if you think of it as the first occurrence time of the Poisson process, this first occurrence will be assigned to the $X$ process, making $M=X$, with probability $\lambda/(\lambda + \mu)$, and to the $Y$ process, making $M \ne X$, with probability $\mu/(\lambda + \mu)$.  This does not depend on the value of $M$.

Comment: Thanks! I am still not clear on this but as with other things in Stochastic Processes, I'll just have to take my time to understand it.